# How to control iPhone "Personal Hotspot" via Terminal

Tags: network, command-line, tethering

I'm a recent convert to Alfred and want to build workflows to connect and disconnect my MacBook to my iPhone's Personal Hotspot. Are these commands easily available in Terminal please? I've looked here and searched more widely, but only find directions to WiFi networks. If the Personal Hotspot is controlled by the same commands, what will its network name be, please?

Comment: For help you may need to indicate what Mac and what version of macOS you have. Also you might find more Alfred experts here: https://www.alfredforum.com/